# Pythons fetchall eats all my swap memory

Tags: python, sqlite, cursor, fetchall

I'm executing a query on a table where I get a column with some hundred million rows back, this is because I want to plot them in a histogram. The problem is that this eats up nearly all my memory (7.8 gb) and all my swap memory (8gb) before the program exits with exit code -9 before cur.fetchall() is done.

How can I prevent this from happening? Should I sort my column first, then do several queries on chuncks of it - or is there maybe a better way to fetch the data in my query? The cur.execute itself takes almost no time.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3 as lite
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def getQuantity(databasepath):
    con = lite.connect(databasepath)
    binwidth = 1
    start = time.time()
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT latitude FROM MessageType1')
        con.commit()
        latitudes = cur.fetchall() #Breakdown here
        latitudes = [x[0] for x in latitudes]
        plt.hist(latitudes, bins=range(int(min(latitudes)), int(max(latitudes)) + binwidth, binwidth))
        plt.title("Bucket size: " + str(binwidth))
        plt.ylabel("Number of message")
        plt.savefig('latlongstats'+'t'+str(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")), format='png')

if __name__ == "__main__":

    getQuantity('database/database.db')
```

Comment: Try using  a generator expression `latitudes = (x[0] for x in latitudes)`

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, the exit code and error comes before cur.fetchall has had the chance to finish.

Comment: Not sure what you can do then, plotting is a bit of a memory hog too so the fact you have so much data probably means you just don't have enough ram

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I certainly need some better hardware for this kind of analysis, but I acually found a way I could cope with this if you see my answer under.

Comment: if you combine it with a generator you may get a performance increase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I replaced the following:

```
    latitudes = cur.fetchall()
    print "fetched"
    latitudes = [x[0] for x in latitudes]
```

with:

```
    while True:
        tmp = cur.fetchone()
        if tmp != None:
            latitudes.append(tmp[0])
        else:
            break
```

I got the same result, allthough it takes forever, and only nearly eats up my ram (but not my swap).